# ReactJS: Converting simple example to Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Newbie** Question

I have an example ReactJS script in `Javascript` that I have `translated` to `Typescript`. Without using too many "any" types, is there a shorter way?

Javascript version:

```
const App = ({title}) => (
  <div>{title}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
   <App title="Xamarin" />,
   document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

My Typescript attempt:

```
interface IApp {
  title:string
}

class App extends React.Component<IApp, any> {

  constructor(props: IApp) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...props };
  }

  public render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>{this.state.title}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
    }
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App title="Xamarin"  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: You not only converted it from js to ts, but also from a functional component to a class-based one. Hence a question: why did you switch from a functional component in the very first place? Typed functional component would be as concise as the original JS version.

Comment: The system we will be building will be Typescript and ReactJS. I am learning, but many examples are in JS only.

Comment: `const App = ({title}: IApp) => (
  <div>{title}</div>
);` --- here is a TS version of your original JS component.

Comment: @zerkms, dude. that's great. Basically, just add a type to the anonymouse type holding {title}. nice

Comment: "just add a type" --- that's the whole idea of TS: you just add types. Unless it's sarcasm and I couldn't detect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any additional state when converting to typescript, simply add the prop interface as you've already indicated. You can do this a couple ways:

1) Indicating the type of your props directly:

```
interface IApp {
  title: string
}

const App = ({title}: IApp) => (
  <div>{title}</div>
);
```

2) Indicating that your function is a React coponent (In this case `React.FC` is shorthand for React FunctionComponent) and then passing your prop interface as a "generic" to that `React.FC` type:

```
interface IApp {
  title: string
}

const App: React.FC<IApp> = ({title}) => (
  <div>{title}</div>
);
```